# Can I set version number of SharePoint Online documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, versioning, version-history, spo

I've just read these two questions:

- "[Set version of a document](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/set-version-of-a-document)"
- "[Is it possible to set the version number of SharePoint document?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235743/is-it-possible-to-set-the-version-number-of-sharepoint-document/270199#270199)"

but I would like to be sure that nothing has changed and that I even can't set version number of a document in SPO via CSOM or PowerShell, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Mohamed said El-Qassas from the link, it's not possible to set the document version number manually in all SharePoint versions.

Workaround: Try to delete the versions until reach to the desired version.

Comment: Yes, I think so, maybe by a PowerShell script I'll repeat "check in" and "check out" operations and at the end I'll delete the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing changed because this would be against the concept of versioning. If you need a controlled Versionnumber create a field where you can freely choose a value.

Comment: It's a solution I considered but, in my case, it is not suitable but thanks for your advice.
As for "the concept of versioning": if a document has a previous history SPO doesn't allow to show this information to users, maybe SPO should be more flexible.